# CentOS 6.6 ipset, can't load kernel module

Tags: centos

Is package ipset on CentOS 6.6 broken, or is this an effect of virtual hosting?

Installing ipset via `yum install ipset` installs a kernel module, ip_set.ko in the following directories:

```
/lib/modules/2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64/kernel/net/netfilter/ipset/ip_set.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/kernel/net/netfilter/ipset/ip_set.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/kernel/net/netfilter/ipset/ip_set.ko
```

`uname -r` returns:
2.6.32-042stab094.7

`modprobe -v ip_set` returns:
FATAL: Module ip_set not found.

`insmod` on any of those modules returns:

```
insmod: error inserting '/lib/modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/kernel/net/netfilter/ipset/ip_set.ko': -1 Operation not permitted
```